# Openlayer 2 set label to middle of vector line

Tags: javascript, google-maps, openlayers

Guys I used Openlayer 2 for creating a layer on Google map.

I draw a Vector Line using Openlayer 2 and I want to set label middle of that line.

below is my code.

```
 var ol = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();
            var vector = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector( "Lines" );

            for (var i = 0; i < fromtoLatlngObject.data.length; i++) {

                var start_point = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(fromtoLatlngObject.data[i].from.lng,fromtoLatlngObject.data[i].from.lat);
                var end_point = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(fromtoLatlngObject.data[i].to.lng,fromtoLatlngObject.data[i].to.lat);

                var firstLine = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(new OpenLayers.Geometry.LineString([start_point, end_point]).transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913")));

                vector.addFeatures([
                    firstLine
                ]);
            }

            var selected_polygon_style = {
                strokeWidth: 2,
                strokeColor: 'blue',
                fontColor: "red",
                fontSize: "16px",
                fontFamily: "arial, monospace",
                fontWeight: "bold",
                fontColor: "green",
                label: "To: test",
                labelAlign: "cm"
            };

            vector.style = selected_polygon_style;
            map.addLayers([ol,vector]);

            var markers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers( "Marker" );
            map.addLayer(markers);

            for (var i = 0; i < latlngObj.data.length; i++) {
                addMarker(latlngObj,map,markers,i);
            }

        }
```

as per Openlayer 2 Document we can set the labelAlign like.

```
labelAlign: "cm",
```

I set the labelAlign but not working also you can check in document.

http://dev.openlayers.org/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Feature/Vector-js.html

or you can also see in the demo given by the Openlayer 2.

http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/vector-features-with-text.html

Thanks

Comment: Are the other style properties working?

Comment: @FrancescoD'Alesio Yes style properties is working but label display at the end of vector line. I want to display it vertically center of vector line.

Comment: Take a look into svg.js to method drawText(). In my option the label will every time centered to the last point in the line, that is of course wrong. A workround could be to build a multiFeature, a line and a point middle of the line and just to label the point.

Comment: have you tried this solution: [http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/113024/13157] from gis.stackexchange? There is a solution which calculates the position of the label in the middle of a line.